# Calculate the average sales of every state using the Subtotal function on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to excel functions and I've been asked to calculate the average sales for every state using the "Subtotal" function.

The dataset is like this:

| State | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| California | 22,5 |
| Utah | 75 |
| Utah | 122,4 |
| California | 99 |
| Texas | 101,3 |
| Indiana | 47 |
| Texas | 136 |

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want to average by state only visible rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Subtotal is the best fit here. My first instinct would be to use a pivot table. You can also get the same answers with dynamic array formulas.

[image]

Formula in D3:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(StatesTable[State]))
```

Formula in E3:

```
=SUMIFS(StatesTable[Sales],StatesTable[State],D3#)/COUNTIFS(StatesTable[State],D3#)
```